# Trying to scrape email using beautifulsoup

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to scrape email to scrape email but it give me `none`. these is page link: https://www.avocats-lille.com//fr/annuaire/avocats-du-tableau-au-barreau-de-lille/2?view=entry

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from time import sleep

headers ={
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'
}
base_url='https://www.avocats-lille.com/'
url = 'https://www.avocats-lille.com/fr/annuaire/avocats-du-tableau-au-barreau-de-lille?view=entries'
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
tra = soup.find_all('h2',class_='title')
productlinks=[]
for links in tra:
    for link in links.find_all('a',href=True):
        comp=base_url+link['href']
        productlinks.append(comp)
        
for link in productlinks:
    r =requests.get(link,headers=headers)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    sleep(5)
    details=soup.find_all("div",class_="item col-5")
    for detail in details:
        email=soup.find('a[href^="mailto"]')
        print(email)
```

Answer (score 0):

Links you are looking for are not inside the `tra` (title) elements.
You should change the code as following to make it working:

```py
tra = soup.find_all('div',class_='item')
```

Comment: they again give me none

Comment: That's strange. I'm not familiar with bs4 syntax, but I see the blocks containing the data of each advocate is matching this CSS Selector: `div.item` Inside these blocks there are links matching `a[href]` CSS Selector locator. Or in XPath way `//div[@class='item']` and `//a[@href]` respectively

Answer (score 0):

The *Email* address is within the following element:

```
<a href="mailto:kamelabbas2002@yahoo.fr">kamelabbas2002@yahoo.fr</a>
```

---

### Solution

Using ***Selenium*** to print the *Email* address i.e. the *`innertext`* attribute you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://www.avocats-lille.com//fr/annuaire/avocats-du-tableau-au-barreau-de-lille/2?view=entry'})
  print(driver.find_element("css selector", 'a[href^="mailto"]').text)
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://www.avocats-lille.com//fr/annuaire/avocats-du-tableau-au-barreau-de-lille/2?view=entry'})
  print(driver.find_element("xpath", '//a[starts-with(@href, "mailto")]').text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  kamelabbas2002@yahoo.fr
  ```